# Neo4j 1.9.2: Query/filter and count multiple node types

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j 1.9.2, I'd like to count all the relationships for EACH node in a set of nodes.

All of my nodes have three properties: `type`, `id`, and `created`.  They're all connected by a "follow" relationship.  Here's an example of how they fit together:

```
user('id:1')-[follows]->review('id:1')
user('id:1')-[follows]->user('id:2')
user('id:2')-[follows]->review('id:1')
```

You get the idea.

The results should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    followers: 2,
    id: 1
    created: 2013-12-13T12:13:42-08:00
    type: review
  },
  {
    followers: 1,
    id: 2,
    created: 2012-02-13T12:13:43-08:00
    type: user
  },
  {
    followers: 0,
    id: 1,
    created: 2012-02-13T12:13:43-08:00,
    type: user
  }
]
```

The data I'm given is essentially the following:

```
{
  users: [1, 2],
  reviews: [1]
}
```

I've tried queries like this:

```
start user1=node:user('id:1'),
      user2=node:user('id:2'),
      review1=node:review1('id:1')

match user1<-[user1_f:follows]-(),
      user2<-[user2_f:follows]-(),
      review1<-[review1_f:follows]-()

return user1, count(user1_f),
       user2, count(user2_f),
       review1, count(review1_f);
```

But obviously this is untenable for large lists of `node:id` pairs (in fact, Neo dies really hard once the query gets large).

Any idea how to achieve this?  I've been pouring over the docs to see if there's some way, but I am not sure there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to run the count operation for a lot of nodes, consider using the index like this:

```
 start users=node:user('id:(1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4)')
 match user<-[f:follows]-(),
 return user, count(f);
```

For reviews, either run a separate query or create an index holding both users and reviews.
If you have multiple start points separated by comma, there is the danger of  running into cross products within the match.

PS: Neo4j 1.9.2 is pretty much outdated - consider upgrading!

Comment: Yeah we'd love to update, unfortunately it's not possible at the moment.  It's on the roadmap though!  So what I'm hearing is that there is no way to do this across multiple totally arbitrary types unless you index every possible combination.  I think it'd be better to just do one query per type (since we don't have that many different types).  Thanks!

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this optimization, and I got a 10x reduction in response time.  Super helpful!